# In seek of a (counter)example

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, gap

I am looking for an example of a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with the following property:

> The number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$ which are isomorphic to $N_G(H)$ is strictly larger than the number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$ which are isomorphic to $H$.

---

I've figured out how to check for this property with GAP, so I'll paste my code below in case anyone finds it useful. (The bit that was giving me trouble was the sixth line of the code.)

```
# given a finite group G, compute the number of conjugacy classes 
# of subgroups of G which are isomorphic to a given subgroup H.
nccs_isom := function(G,H)
local ccs, K, count;
ccs:=List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative);
count := 0;
for K in ccs do
  if IdSmallGroup(K) = IdSmallGroup(H) then
    count := count+1;
  fi;
od;
return count;
end;

grps:=AllSmallGroups([1..100],IsAbelian,false);;

# the actual search
for g in grps do
  ccs:=List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g),Representative);
  for h in ccs do
    norm:=Normalizer(g,h);
    if nccs_isom(g,norm) > nccs_isom(g,h) then  
      Print(IdSmallGroup(g),"  ",IdSmallGroup(h),"\n");                              
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

Comment: Derek, thanks. Consider posting an answer and include, if you want, any piece of code you used to check this (if indeed you used the computer).

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something foolish, but it doesn't look like $S_4$ and the given $H$ is an example. I get that $S_4$ has two conjugacy classes of subgroups isomorphic to $C_2$ and also two conjugacy classes of subgroups isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$. (The normalizer in $S_4$ of $H = \langle (1,2) \rangle$ is $\langle (1,2) , (3,4)\rangle$.)

Comment: You are right, sorry! I didn't use a computer, and miscalculated! I will try again.

Comment: Note that calling `AllSmallGroups` for a large range causes large overhead. You can see http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups/ for an idea how to write modular code which allows to check one group at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By brute force computer search, I found a counterexample $G=\mathtt{SmallGroup}(64,33)$.

For $H$ take a cyclic subgroup of order $4$ with normalizer of order $8$. There is only one class of such subgroups, and $N_G(H) \cong C_4 \times C_2$.

There are four conjugacy classes of $G$ isomorphic to $H$ and five classes isomorphic to $N_G(H)$.